# Bind Security Warning

Tags: dns, bind

I always seem to find the following message in my Bind logs:

```
security: warning: using built-in root key for view _default
```

Could anybody advise please, what does that mean and how do I fix it? It's all up and running fine.. except for this little warning. Many thanks!

Comment: This is a setting within `named.conf` and relates to DNSSEC. It signals that root keys are in use. Root keys help ensure that the root zone is valid. This article (https://salsa.debian.org/dns-team/bind/blob/master/bind.keys) relates to bind.keys and settings for the root keys as well within the `named.conf` file. See if switching the settings resolves the issue. https://www.isc.org/bind-keys/ has further information about using keys. The warning may just be telling you that you are using the default key which has not been updated/validated

Comment: Thank you so much for your tip, am401! Appreciate! I have now fixed it in a jiffy. It appears to be that these 3 have to go together ONLY like this:                                                    dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation auto;
dnssec-lookaside auto;                                                                                                  I had only dnssec-validation auto set without the other two and it resulted in this warning. In fact, lookaside is outdated now and may be safely skipped, but it's harmless to keep it too. Perfect!

Comment: Glad it was resolved!